# How to add association analysis weights

Tags: r, web-scraping, associations, text-mining

Text mining in R//
How to add association analysis weights

I am doing linkage analysis with TXT file.
My code is all the same now.
There is no indication of which item is more relevant.

If you want to increase the circle size,= High frequency

I want to increase the thickness of the line=High support.
What should I do?

Thank you for your advice.

```
library(KoNLP) 
library(RColorBrewer)
library(wordcloud)

text1<-readLines(file.choose())
text1
Encoding(text1)<- "UTF-8"


text1 <- readLines(text1)
lword <- Map(extractNoun,text1) 
lword <- unique(lword)
lword <- sapply(lword, unique) 
filter1 <- function(x){
  nchar(x) <= 4 && nchar(x) >= 2 && is.hangul(x)
}
filter2 <- function(x){
  Filter(filter1, x)
}
lword <- sapply(lword, filter2)
install.packages("arules")
library(arules) 
wordtran <- as(lword, "transactions")
wordtable <- crossTable(wordtran)
tranrules <- apriori(wordtran, parameter=list(supp=0.01, conf=0.05)) 
inspect(tranrules)
rules <- labels(tranrules, ruleSep=" ")
rules <- sapply(rules, strsplit, " ",  USE.NAMES=F) 
rulemat <- do.call("rbind", rules)
#---------------------------------------------    
#▽Association analysis visualization
#---------------------------------------------  
install.packages("igraph") 
library(igraph)
ruleg <- graph.edgelist(rulemat[c(12:59),], directed=F) 
plot.igraph(ruleg, vertex.label=V(ruleg)$name,
            vertex.label.cex=1.2, vertex.label.color='black', 
            vertex.size=20, vertex.color='gray', vertex.frame.color='blue')
```

Comment: Can you add the result of `dput(ruleg)` to your post? In addition, _"If you want to increase the circle size, I want to increase the thickness of the line. What should I do?" does not make much sense to me. What do you want? Increase vertex sizes, increase edge sizes, both, ..? Please clarify. :)

Comment: @lukeA   increase the circle size,= High frequency
 or  I want to increase the thickness of the line=High support

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
library(igraph)
g <- sample_pa(10)
V(g)$freq <- runif(vcount(g), 1, 10)
E(g)$supp <- rnorm(ecount(g))
vsize <- c(10, 20)
esize <- c(1, 5)
plot(
  g, 
  vertex.size=scales::rescale(V(g)$freq, vsize), 
  edge.width=scales::rescale(E(g)$supp, esize)
)
```